# How to synchronize Python code running on PyCharm with Python code running on Jupyter

Tags: python, pycharm, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am working on a project in which I have to recognize the licence plate number from the image of car, and also the model of car (Mercedes, Toyota, etc.).

I need to write the code in Python to analyze the licence plate number and then run it on PyCharm. I also need to write Python code to recognize the car model as well, but run it on Jupyter.

I want to synchronize these codes to run them one after the other because I want one output after running both of these codes.

I have searched the internet for a potential solution, but have found nothing.